# gevent Open Shift force HTTPS

Tags: python, https, web.py, openshift, gevent

I have a web.py app running on OpenShift via gevent using the Python 2.7 community cart.  I want to force all connections to go through https.  There is a good tutorial on OpenShift for doing this with apache, but what about for gevent?

Here is my app.py, it's basically the default one from the Python 2.7 community cart:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import imp
import os
import sys

try:
   zvirtenv = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'],
                           'virtenv', 'bin', 'activate_this.py')
   execfile(zvirtenv, dict(__file__ = zvirtenv) )
except IOError:
   pass


def run_gevent_server(app, ip, port=8080):
   from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
   WSGIServer((ip, port), app).serve_forever()


def run_simple_httpd_server(app, ip, port=8080):
   from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
   make_server(ip, port, app).serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   ip   = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
   port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT'])
   zapp = imp.load_source('application', 'wsgi/application')
   #  Use gevent if we have it, otherwise run a simple httpd server.
   print 'Starting WSGIServer on %s:%d ... ' % (ip, port)
   try:
      run_gevent_server(zapp.application, ip, port)
   except:
      print 'gevent probably not installed - using default simple server ...'
      run_simple_httpd_server(zapp.application, ip, port)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using nginx to terminate SSL (https) connections and proxy requests to your application. Here is the simple nginx config

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    upstream app_server {
        server 127.0.0.1:5001 fail_timeout=0;  
    }

    server {
        listen <OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP>:<OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT>;
        server_name <DOMAIN_NAME>;

        ssl                 on;
        ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers         AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-MD5;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;
        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
    }
}
```

It's a striped down version of one of my servers (hope I haven't droped anything necessary).

The main problem with proxy servers is wrong headers like `HOST`, `REMOTE_ADDR` and so on. But this configuration and especially `proxy_set_header` commands help most of web frameworks to figure out who is the real sender.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I mentioned this is running on OpenShift, a cloud platform and I cannot utilize nginx through it.

Comment: Why not? There are a lot of examples of installation of nginx into OpenShift plus a pack of cartridges.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know gevent doesn't provide SSL support for built-in WSGI server as well as wsgiref's one.

If you wish to use gevent, you may look at uwsgi with "--gevent" option but you have to implement WSGI entry point in your app.py itself. I believe the rest configuration is the same as presents in apache tutorial.

PS: most probably that uwsgi also supports SSL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't exactly understand what you think my next steps should be?  Can you point me to some documentation?  What source changes should I be making in app.py?

Comment: Could you provide link to apache tutorial? Probably I could make difference between apache tutorial and how to setup SSL and gevent.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1044-how-to-redirect-traffic-to-https